# Setting minimum and maximum number of columns using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 10 divs (64px x 64px) that I want to display in 5 columns maximum (for Large and Extra Large viewports) and 3 columns minimum (for small viewports like iPhone 7 etc).

I am trying to do this with CSS Grid but not able to do the minimum columns part (It goes to 2 columns even if there is space to fit 3 cols).

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 140px));
  max-width: 800px;
}

.child {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Max width for the grid container is 800px.

Here is the link for [Codepen](https://codepen.io/baggasumit/pen/EeGzJY?editors=1100)

Edit: If possible, I want to accomplish this only using CSS Grid i.e. without using Media Queries or Flexbox.

Answer (score 83):

I was looking for the same answer and since I couldn't find any useful response for this problem, I managed to solve it by myself. Here is my solution that works perfectly fine using only CSS Grid.

**TL;DR**

**Solution A - recommended (3 - 5 columns with a min-width of 64px per column)**

```
/* Note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value */

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5)), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5)), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution B (3 - 5 columns with exactly 64px width per column)**

```
/* Note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value */

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5))));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5))));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Reusable solutions (Sass mixin)**

If you want a reusable function to easily generate a column layout with diferent maximum and minimum column values, allowing you to add some gap between columns or adjusting the minimum width for the columns, you should take advantage of Sass mixins and CSS variables like this:

```
/* For solution A - recommended */
@mixin grid-min-max-cols($min-cols, $max-cols, $cols-min-width, $grid-row-gap: 0px, $grid-column-gap: 0px) {
  --min-cols: #{$min-cols};
  --max-cols: #{$max-cols};
  --cols-min-width: #{$cols-min-width};
  --grid-row-gap: #{$grid-row-gap};
  --grid-column-gap: #{$grid-column-gap};
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min((100%/var(--min-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--min-cols) - 1)/var(--min-cols)), max(var(--cols-min-width), (100%/var(--max-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--max-cols) - 1)/var(--max-cols)))), 1fr));
  gap: var(--grid-row-gap) var(--grid-column-gap);
}

/* For solution B */
@mixin grid-min-max-cols($min-cols, $max-cols, $cols-min-width, $grid-row-gap: 0px, $grid-column-gap: 0px) {
  --min-cols: #{$min-cols};
  --max-cols: #{$max-cols};
  --cols-min-width: #{$cols-min-width};
  --grid-row-gap: #{$grid-row-gap};
  --grid-column-gap: #{$grid-column-gap};
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min((100%/var(--min-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--min-cols) - 1)/var(--min-cols)), max(var(--cols-min-width), (100%/var(--max-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--max-cols) - 1)/var(--max-cols))))));
  gap: $grid-row-gap $grid-column-gap;
}

.parent {
  @include grid-min-max-cols(3, 5, 64px, 5px, 5px);
}
```

Check my CodePen to see a fully functional example of both reusable solutions (A and B):

https://codepen.io/btous/pen/QWvGNGm

**Similar approach with flexbox**

Check my CodePen to see a fully functional example of a similar approach with flexbox:

https://codepen.io/btous/pen/OJzwdJw

**LETS GO DEEPER!**

**Understanding the `minmax()` function within the `grid-template-columns` CSS property**

The CSS `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min, max))` statement, tells the browser to calculate the number of columns for an element container based on its own width and the `min` and `max` values for the `minmax()` function. So the key to solve this problem is to understand how the `minmax(min, max)` function works inside the `repeat()` function, on the `grid-template-columns` CSS property.

1. If we have a grid container with the following CSS property and value, `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min, max)`, it takes the container and divides it with as many columns as can fit with the width of the `max` parameter for `minmax()`. So if we set the `grid-template-columns` property to `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 100px)` on a 500px container, it will divide it into 5 columns of 100px since this is the `max` parameter for the `minmax()` function.
2. In case the container increases its width to 550px it still can fit up to 5 columns (since to fit another 100px column it should be at least 600px wide), but it will have a 50px remaining space that will be left empty.
3. If the second value of `minmax()` function is smaller than the first one, it takes the first value as its final value, so `minmax(100px, 50px)` will result into 100px.
4. If the `max` value is set to 1fr (1 fraction), the browser will behaves as explained in the first and second points but taking the `min` value to calculate the number of the columns to divide the container and, if there is any remaining space, it will distributed equally between all the columns. So if we set the `grid-template-columns` property to `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)` on a container with the same width of the container defined on the second point (550px) it still will fit up to 5 columns and will have a 50px remaining space, but this remaining space won't be left empty, instead it will be distributed equally with all the 5 columns (20px per column) resulting on a 5 columns layout of 120px each.

See this CSS-TRICKS post for more details:

https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit

Now that we know how it works, we can face the problem and solve it step by step to set the `min` and `max` parameters for the `minmax()` function.

We have 2 different approaches to let the `grid-template-columns` property calculates the number of columns:

- The first one, as explained on the fourth point, is to **set the `min` value to the width we want for each column** and the `max` value to 1fr

  ```
  minmax(?px, 1fr)
  ```
- The second one, as explained on the first two points, is to **set the `max` value to the width we want for each column** and the `min` value to 0px since we want to ensure that the `min` parameter is never higher than the `max` one to avoid it will be taken as the final value as explained on the third point

  ```
  minmax(0px, ?px)
  ```

The point here is that if the value set for the **?** sign is static, when the container can fit more than the maximum number of columns desired, it will keep adding them to the layout and when there is no available space in the container to fit the minimum number of columns desired, it will keep removing them from the layout.

Ok then, now we know that we need to let the browser calculates this value dynamically, to ensure it never breaks our maximum and minimum columns layout defined, so let's do it!

**Calculate the columns width dynamically for the `minmax()` function**

This is the trickiest part. First of all we need that the number of columns never exceeds the maximum number of columns we desire (in your case it's 5, but could be any value).

To accomplish that, we have to ensure that the columns width never exceeds the container width divided by the maximum number of columns (5 for you), i.e. 100%/5, so for now we have the following:

```
/* For solution A - recommended (note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(100%/5), 1fr));
}

/* For solution B (note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, calc(100%/5)));
}
```

Cool, now the layout doesn't exceed the maximum of 5 columns, but it always returns a 5 columns layout since the container will always could fit 5 columns of its same width divided by 5. See snippets below:

Solution A:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(100%/5), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Solution B:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, calc(100%/5)));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

To make layout reduce columns when it reduces its width we have to tell him the minimum column width you want, i.e. 64px, so it can start removing columns whenever them don't fit in the container width.

We'll do that by wrapping the parameter of the `minmax()` function inside a `max()` function that will take the maximum value between our 2 parameters (the desired minimum column width, i.e. 64px, and the one we already have, i.e. calc(100%/5)), giving us the following:

```
/* For solution A - recommended (note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max(64px, 100%/5), 1fr));
}

/* For solution B (note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, max(64px, 100%/5)));
}
```

Note that we don't need the `calc()` function to operate inside the `max()`.

With the code above, whenever the result of 100%/5 is less than 64px it will set the `max()` function value to 64px and the `minmax()` function will be converted to `minmax(64px, 1fr)` (for solution A) or `minmax(0, 64px)` (for solution B) and will divide the container width by 64px to calculate how many columns can fit. See snippets below:

Solution A:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max(64px, 100%/5), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Solution B:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, max(64px, 100%/5)));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now we have properly set the maximum number of columns but still need to set the minimum (3 in your case). For that we need to ensure that the parameter for `minmax()` will never be higher than a third part of the container, i.e. 100%/3.

We will do that by wrapping again the parameter of the `minmax()` function, but in this case inside a `min()` function, and besides the value we already have, i.e. `max(64px, 100%/5)`, we will add the value found in the previous paragraph, resulting in the following:

```
/* For solution A - recommended (note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5)), 1fr));
}

/* For solution B (note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5))));
}
```

You can see their behavior on the snippets below:

Solution A:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5)), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Solution B:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3, max(64px, 100%/5))));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Allowing a CSS column gap**

With that, we already have set up your layout, but it will be nice to set a gap to our grid without breaking it, so lets do it!

If we want to set a `column-gap` property (since the row gap won't affect our layout) to, lets say, 5px, when we calculate the columns width to set the layout we have to take this property into account. If not, it will break.

To do that we have to subtract the gap for each column from the operations to calculate the `max` parameter for the `minmax()` function.

We can get the proportional column gap for each column multiplying the `column-gap` value by the number of columns minus one, since there is always one less gap than columns. That will result in:

```
/* For solution A - recommended (note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3 - 5px*(3-1)/3, max(64px, 100%/5 - 5px*(5-1)/5)), 1fr));
}

/* For solution B (note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value) */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3 - 5px*(3-1)/3, max(64px, 100%/5 - 5px*(5-1)/5))));
}
```

See their behavior on the snippets below:

Solution A:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%/3 - 5px*(3-1)/3, max(64px, 100%/5 - 5px*(5-1)/5)), 1fr));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Solution B:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min(100%/3 - 5px*(3-1)/3, max(64px, 100%/5 - 5px*(5-1)/5))));
}

.child {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Styles not related to the goal */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  background: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<p>You can resize the blue container</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Making a reusable function for any number of minimum and maximum columns, any column minimum width and any `column-gap` value**

We have already achieved our goal of making a responsive layout of a maximum of 5 and a minimum of 3 columns, a minimum width for each column of 64px and a gap of 5px between the columns. This looks really nice, but what if for some reason we want to change one of this properties value or some of them? We will have to review the `grid-template-columns` property and after remembering and understanding all the functions and numbers, change it to what we need.

Why not taking advantage of Sass mixins and CSS variables to make it as simple as changing the value we want to change on its variable and let the code do the rest for us?

We can create a mixin that takes `min-cols`, `max-cols`, `cols-min-width` and `grid-column-gap` as its parameters and replace the explicit values on the `grid-template-columns` property for them. Then in the container selector on the CSS file we can include this mixin and set a variable for each one of this values to make it more clear whenever we have to change any of them.

In SCSS it will look like this:

```
/* For solution A - recommended (note the difference with solution B on the grid-template-columns value) */
@mixin grid-min-max-cols($min-cols, $max-cols, $cols-min-width, $grid-row-gap: 0px, $grid-column-gap: 0px) {
  --min-cols: #{$min-cols};
  --max-cols: #{$max-cols};
  --cols-min-width: #{$cols-min-width};
  --grid-row-gap: #{$grid-row-gap};
  --grid-column-gap: #{$grid-column-gap};
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min((100%/var(--min-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--min-cols) - 1)/var(--min-cols)), max(var(--cols-min-width), (100%/var(--max-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--max-cols) - 1)/var(--max-cols)))), 1fr));
  gap: $grid-row-gap $grid-column-gap;
}

/* For solution B (note the difference with solution A on the grid-template-columns value) */
@mixin grid-min-max-cols($min-cols, $max-cols, $cols-min-width, $grid-row-gap: 0px, $grid-column-gap: 0px) {
  --min-cols: #{$min-cols};
  --max-cols: #{$max-cols};
  --cols-min-width: #{$cols-min-width};
  --grid-row-gap: #{$grid-row-gap};
  --grid-column-gap: #{$grid-column-gap};
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min((100%/var(--min-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--min-cols) - 1)/var(--min-cols)), max(var(--cols-min-width), (100%/var(--max-cols) - var(--grid-column-gap)*(var(--max-cols) - 1)/var(--max-cols))))));
  gap: var(--grid-row-gap) var(--grid-column-gap);
}

.parent {
  @include grid-min-max-cols(3, 5, 64px, 5px, 5px);
}
```

With that, we have all we need to generate our nice columns layout with a maximum and a minimum columns number.

Comment: Too bad I can't double upvote this post. Thank you!

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: This is a really excellent answer. Thank you!

Comment: The third code block, on "For solution A" did the trick for me. Thank you!!

Comment: To make it work with Firefox and safari, it's necessary tu add calc() inside the calculations of min() and max() functions

Comment: Hi @DanielaWitteveen, sorry for the late response. **I have tested it** in Safari 14 and above (iOS), Safari 13.1 and above (Mac), Firefox in Windows and Mac... and **it is always working fine in all browsers**. Are you sure you are having problems with this? Could you give me more info about your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

you can get required output by using `@media` query used `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);` for large device and `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`; for small device

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);  
}

.child {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: brown;
}

@media(max-width:540px){
  .parent {
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to do this without using media queries or flexbox? Sorry, I added this condition after posting the question. I have mentioned it at the end of the question.

Comment: It might be possible and browser support will be limited. media query will provide the freedom that you can make any kind of layout based on regulation.. so need to approach better option

Answer (score 8):

I think this is you are looking for.

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 120px));
  max-width: 800px;
}

.child {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have changed - `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 140px));` to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 120px));`

Because in the small screen size the child will take `140px` area reserved resulting it to break to 2 columns in small screen now I have changed it to `120px` and `grid-gap: 2vw;` to sove this issue.

I hope this was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps

https://codepen.io/pandiyancool/pen/oPmgeP

css

```
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1 1 160px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to do this without using media queries or flexbox? Sorry, I should have included this in the question. Edited now.

Comment: Too late someone already down voted :( I spent few mins to do this, so now it's wasted

Comment: redemption vote! It's a good solution and can be helpful to recommend options other than what has been asked for... I think at the very least it doesn't deserve a negative score :)

Comment: double redemption!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mind fluid columns, but using media queries you could do:

`.parent { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }`
for small screens

and

`.parent { grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); }`
for larger screens

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to do this without using media queries or flexbox? Sorry, I should have included this in the question. Edited now.

Comment: Probably, and I reckon minmax is the way to go, especially since your divs are fixed width.

Answer (score -2):

For Max Width Answer of @weBBer is Ok But you should set min-width (N)px

Answer (score -3):

I just found a neat trick that worked for me. I'm using chrome.

```css
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
```